# How to add Column values based on unique value of a different column

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to add values in Column B based on unique value in Column A. How can i do it using AWK (or) Any other way using bash?

```
Column_A | Column_B
--------------------
A        | 1
A        | 2
A        | 1
B        | 3
B        | 8
C        | 5
C        | 8
```

Result:

```
Column_A | Column_B
--------------------
A        | 6
B        | 11
C        | 13
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that your Input_file is same as shown, sorted with first field, could you please try following(will edit solution for alignment too soon).

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  OFS=" | "
}
FNR==1 || /^-/{
  print
  next
}
prev!=$1 && prev{
  print prev,sum
  prev=sum=""
}
{
  sum+=$NF
  prev=$1
}
END{
  if(prev && sum){
    print prev,sum
  }
}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

another `awk`

```
$ awk 'NR<3 {print; next} 
            {a[$1]+=$NF; line[$1]=$0} 
       END  {for(k in a) {sub(/[0-9]+$/,a[k],line[k]); print line[k]}}' file

Column_A | Column_B
--------------------
A        | 4
B        | 11
C        | 13
```

note that A totals to 4, not 6.

Answer (score -1):

One possible solution (Assuming file is in CSV format):

Input :

```
$ cat csvtest.csv
A,1
A,2
A,3
B,3
B,8
C,5
C,8
```

```
$ cat csvtest.csv | awk -F "," '{arr[$1]+=$2} END {for (i in arr) {print i","arr[i]}}'
A,6
B,11
C,13
```